# How to concatenate text files into a pipe?

Tags: windows-7, cmd

What command will concatenate text files matching wildcard pattern into a pipe? I'd like to recode e.g.

```
COPY Q:\Playlists\*.m3u %TEMP%\all.txt /b >nul
SORT %TEMP%\all.txt > %ALL%
```

without a temp file e.g.

```
somecommand Q:\Playlists\*.m3u | sort > %ALL%
```

COPY without a destination filename copies to the current directory, not a pipe (and litters the console with filenames). TYPE with a wildcard source inserts unwanted filepaths in the output. EDIT: As MC ND points out, TYPE's unwanted output goes to stderr, not to the pipe (stdout).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost done. Just remove the unwanted output of the type command

```
type Q:\Playlists\*.m3u 2>nul | sort > %ALL%
```

When the `type` command processes more than one file, the list of processed files is echoed to the standard error stream, that is, stream number 2. So, take stream 2 and redirect it to nul

**edited** to adapt to comments.

As indicated, `type` command only outputs the file names when more than a file in involved in the operation. So, you can use the `type` command on only one file and iterate over the list

```
(for %%a in (*.m3u) do type "%%a") | sort > %ALL%
```

Comment: Thanks. That has the slight downside of losing genuine error messages. Do you know solution that does not?

Comment: @ChrisJJ, alternative included.

Comment: Thanks. It is good to be reminded of concatenation by (...) for other cases too.

Comment: I find a fault. %ALL% includes the echoed TYPE commands. Fix: (for %%a in (*.m3u) do @type "%%a") | sort > %ALL%

Comment: @ChrisJJ, the output will include the `type` commands in the case you have `echo on`. If this is your case (sorry, i usually run all batch files with `echo off`), of course, the inclusion of the @ will be equivalent to a `echo off` only for the command it prefixes.